# Microsoft.Data.Sqlite issue with apostrophe characters in password

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, entity-framework-core, sqlcipher

I'm using EF Core 6 with the MS SQLite driver and the SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlcipher so the database is being encrypted by SqlCipher. if I pass a apostrophe character in the password then the apostrophe character is being doubled in the password. For example if I use the following connection string when creating a database:

`@"Data Source=c:\temp\test.db;password=""123'"""`

When I try to access the database the password to the database is 123''. I have tried using pragma key as well and get the same issue. I create a new database and then immediately execute the following SQLite Pragma command:

`pragma key='123'''`    Note: the apostrophe is escaped with another apostrophe)

and again the password to access the database is set as 123''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is not a fault in EF Core, the MS SQLite Drivers or SqlCipher.

I was using a program called SQLiteStudio to access the database and view the contents. The fault is in SQLiteStudio, if the password contains an apostrophe you have to enter it twice.

I proved this by downloading a copy of DB Browser for Sqlite and this let me access the database by typing the correct password.

Sorry for wasting peoples time!